# for custom fonts is it necessary to add ActionBarActivity for Typeface?

Tags: android, fonts, android-actionbaractivity, android-typeface

I was reading about Custom Fonts in Android, But i have Confusion that for using Typeface(for getting your custom font from assets) is it possible to add any other activity type than `ActionBarActivity()`.

someone please clarify my doubt.

Comment: where did you read that ?

Comment: from Tutorials Point.

Comment: share link here..

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

it is saying to add font file in asset folder so where i have to add that folder will you please tell me, i am not much aware of this topic.

Comment: @amit pandya you got it totally wrong its just an example if you want you can use YourActivity extends Activity and they have not mentioned any other thing its your imagination'

Comment: there is no connection between ActionbarActivity and Typeface. so you can use AppCompatActivty also.

Comment: @amit pandya At least try before you ask!! inheritance is something set a custom font is something

Comment: thanx for your help @Charuක 
but where i have to add the folder in project. i have downloaded the fonts file

Comment: open your application folder, goto src --> main --> and add here "assets"

Comment: thanku for your help @SagarChavada

Comment: and also in assets folder add one other folder named "fonts" like tutorial says..  afterwards follow those tuts.

Comment: @amit pandya check the image it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, There is no relationship your tutorial just demoed it under an activity which extends ActionBarActivity.

[image] [image]

Right click on that > new Directory name it as fonts > copy your fonts to that

Then if you have a `TextView` that you need to apply your font

```
TextView myTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
Typeface typeFace=Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(),"fonts/your_cutom_font_name.ttf");
myTextView.setTypeface(typeFace);
```